# Cygwin unexpected token `(' with grep

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am using Cygwin on Windows 7 OS.

I am trying to match an email of this format: `x.y@enron.com`

This is my regex:

```
grep [a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+@(E|e)nron\.com
```

it returns

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

It works when used in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

It should match emails like `a.z@enron.com` and `ros.cab@Enron.com`

Comment: How are you using it? It should be single quoted to avoid shell keywords from being parsed.

Comment: it doesn't match when i single quote it

Comment: @AndresZW:  Does it match when it errors?  Are you using `grep -E`?

Comment: Again, how are you using it? Is it in `grep -Ex that-regex somefile`, in `[[ $string =~ that-regex ]]`? What version of bash?

Comment: using it with grep

Comment: @AndresZW that regex requires `-E` to work.

Comment: I am using Cygwin @StéphaneChazelas . Downloaded from their website last week

Comment: Please edit your question using the "edit" link and include the exact code you're using and what you expect it do do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[`, `\`, `(` and `)` all have special meanings to the shell and should be quoted if you intend to pass them verbatim in an argument to a command (here `grep`).

Also note that ranges like `[a-z]` make little sense outside of the C locale.

So here, you probably want:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -xE '[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+@(E|e)nron\.com' < some-file
```

Or:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -xE '[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+@[Ee]nron\.com' < some-file
```

To report the lines that match that `E`xtended regular expression e`x`actly. With the `al`pha`num`erical characters limited to those of the `C` locale (so on Cygwin, ASCII English/latin letters without diacritics and Arabic decimal digits; in the C locale `[[:alnum:]]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]` match the same thing).

Above using the `'...'` form of quoting that is the strongest one (no character is special within them).

`+`, `|`, `(...)` are *extended* regexp operator (not *basic* regexp operators as expected by `grep` without `-E`). Without `-x`, `grep` would look for matches *within* the lines, so for example would match on a line like:

```
foo@bar.com x.y.z@enron.common.br whatever
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Without `LC_ALL=C`, `[[:alnum:]]` could match on characters of other alphetical scripts (like the Greek, Cyrillic, Korean ones), and `[a-z]` could match on some latin characters with diacritics like `á`, `ç`, `ÿ` but not others like `ẑ`, `ź` as they come *after* `z`...

Comment: I think the solution is the use of LC_ALL=C.

Comment: Finally, how would it be if i want every emails that are not in that format?

Comment: @AndresZW, add `-v` to report the lines that don't match.

Comment: @AndresZW, see edit about `LC_ALL=C`. I'd say it's the most minor of the problems in your original code.

Comment: How about the use of negative lookaround: (?!pattern)

Comment: @AndresZW, that's a `perl` regexp operator. GNU `grep` as found on Cygwin supports them with the `-P` option (instead of of `-E`).